# Vue-router 2 changes route but does not update the view?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a login issue with website that uses:

- Vue.js  v2.0.3
- vue-router v2.0.1
- vuex v0.8.2

In `routes.js` I have a simple interceptor setup

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!router.app.auth.isUserLoggedIn) {
        next({
            path: '/login',
            query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
    } else {
        next()
    }
} else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
}
```

})

And in `login.vue`,which handles the login page logic after using Google API only for login succeeds I call this:

```
this.login(userData).then( 
    () => this.$router.push(this.redirectToAfterLogin), // Login success
    () => {} // Login failed
)


mounted: function(){
if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn){
            // Let's just redirect to the main page
            this.$router.push(this.redirectToAfterLogins)
        }else{
            Vue.nextTick(() => {
                this.loadGooglePlatform()
            })}}


computed: {
        redirectToAfterLogin: function() {
            if (this.$route.query.redirect){
                return this.$route.query.redirect
            }else{
                return '/'
            }
        }
    }
```

router.js

```
var VueRouter = require('vue-router')

// Router setup
export const router = new VueRouter({
    linkActiveClass: "is-active",
    mode: 'history',
    saveScrollPosition: true,
    routes: [
        { path: '', name: 'root', redirect: '/home' },
        { path: '/login', name: 'login', meta: { loadingNotRequired: true }, component: require('./pages/login.vue') },
        { path: '/logout', name: 'logout', meta: { loadingNotRequired: true }, component: require('./pages/logout.vue') },
        { path: '/home', name: 'home', title: 'Home', redirect: '/home/random', component: require('./pages/home.vue'),
            children: [
                { path: 'random', name: 'random', meta: { requiresAuth: true }, title: 'Random', component: require('./pages/random.vue') }
            ]  
        }
    ]
})

// Redirect to login page if not logged In
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        // this route requires auth, check if logged in
        // if not, redirect to login page.
        if (!router.app.auth.isUserLoggedIn) {
            next({
                path: '/login',
                query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } else {
        next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
})
```

Now here `this.login` is just the call to vuex, to update the logged in user.

What happens is that after login, **URL changes** to /home, but the **DOM does not update**!

Only way that successfully changed the DOM was forcing `location.reload()` and that is not what I want to do, as it loses my dynamically loaded G scripts in Head.

Any idea on what to do to force the view to update DOM?

NOTE: it happens only on the first login of user, if he logs out and back-in, the redirecting is fine

Comment: in `() => this.$router.push(this.redirectToAfterLogin()), // Login success`, did you miss the `()` after `redirectToAfterLogin`?

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 hm...no, that does not seem to be the case, as it occurs in promise, and if I do so, I get Type Error `TypeError: _this2.redirectToAfterLogin is not a function(…)` I edited the code, to show you also mounted section, but not much happen there

Comment: `redirectToAfterLogins` is a computed property, not a function, `()` are not required. Could you show the content of your router config?

Comment: @jeerbl Sure, I added the conf..

Comment: @dscni Did you ever figure it out? I'd love to know the answer

Comment: @nachocab not to this date, I end up using a hack for redirecting it and reloading the view with reloading gapi resources as well :/ but I do plan to rewrite the whole thing soon, and will post the answer here.. Add suggestions if you have any :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but did u checked if on call `this.$router.push(this.redirectToAfterLogin)` the `this` is the component login.vue instead a instance of vuex?

Answer (score 12):

Not a perfect solution may be, as it is going to recreate the component but it will work for every case when having same route & needs to update the component.

Just update the `<router-view/>` or `<router-view></router-view>` with

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Comment: nice and quick fix!

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Vue re-uses components where possible. You should use `beforeRouteUpdate` to react to a route switch that uses the same component.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem "URL changes to /home, but the DOM does not update".
In my project, the tag "transition" maked the problem.
Hope it is helpful！

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the redirectToAfterLogin function into methods, like this it will be recalculated each times. The computed will be modified only if used v-model changed. To stick to the meaning of the function name, I would set the router push inside.

login.vue :

```
mounted: function(){
   if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn){
            // Let's just redirect to the main page
            // this.$router.push(this.redirectToAfterLogins)
            this.redirectToAfterLogins()
   }else{
            Vue.nextTick(() => {
                this.loadGooglePlatform()
            })
   }
},
// computed: {
methods: {
    this.login(userData).then( 
       // () => this.$router.push(this.redirectToAfterLogin), // Login success
       () => this.redirectToAfterLogin(), // Login success
       () => {} // Login failed
    ),
    redirectToAfterLogin: function() {
            
        if (this.$route.query.redirect){
            // return this.$route.query.redirect
            this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect)
        }else{
            // return '/'
            this.$router.push('/')
        }
    }
}
```

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

"However, the difference is that computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed. This means as long as message has not changed, multiple access to the reversedMessage computed property will immediately return the previously computed result without having to run the function again."

methods vs computed and filters :

- [Access vue instance/data inside filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828664/access-vue-instance-data-inside-filter-method/42829248#42829248)