# vue-i18n : how to use inside vue instance filter

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I want to use a **filter** to perform translations. 
Problem is that '**this**' doesn't point to my vue instance inside my filter function.

This is what I currently have.

inside my template I have this:

```
  <p>{{ parking.status | translate }} </p>
```

inside my component I have this:

```
 new Vue({ ...
 filters: {
      translate: function(value, vue) {
          return this.$i18n.t('MLAA-47');
 }
```

The error I get is that this == undefined. 
How do i point it to my vue instance inside my filter function ?

Comment: There's already answered same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828664/access-vue-instance-data-inside-filter-method

Comment: Hi Hannes, did you solve your problem? Any answer helped you? If yes, try to mark as solved to help others & keep S.O clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As points @vitaly-mosin in the comment in that answer explains that you couldn't use `this` inside the filter functions.

> filters are primarily designed for text transformation purposes. For
>   more complex data transforms in other directives, you should use
>   Computed properties instead.

I had the same issue and I resolved moving the translation with $i18n to a computed method, like:

Inside your template, instead of this:

```
 <p>{{ parking.status | translate }} </p>
```

Change it to:

```
<p>{{ translateStatus(parking.status) }} </p>
```

And in the methods:

```
methods: {
    translateStatus (status) {
        return this.$t(status)
    }
},
```

I guess that you have a dynamic status (not returning always: 'MLAA-47') and you should assert that you have translations for all of them. It worked for me!

Hope it helps to you too

Answer (score 0):

We can import file exporting i18n instance like this

```
import i18n from '@/i18n.js'
```

And use it like this

```
i18n.t('your.message')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good idea, but so far it is doing what I want.

Define the filters like

```
// the instance.vue will be set on App.vue
export const instance = {
  vue: null
};

// little helper
const t = (key) => instance.vue?.$t?.(key);

export default {
  filter: (v) => v + t('somekey')
}
```

Then in `App.vue` (or whatever it is you use), do

```
import {instance} from '@/filters'

export default {
  mounted() {
    instance.vue = this; // set the instance here
```