# Using a prop inside a filter?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wish to filter some text on my component:

```
<p :v-text="'hello' | prefix"></p>
```

My filter looks like:

```
prefix(string) {
   return inputPrefix + string;
}
```

`inputPrefix` is just a prop....

```
<my-component input-prefix="some-prefix_" ....
```

But I get the error `inputPrefix is not defined`

How can I use a prop in a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In filters you can not access this. Use the filter in this way,

```
   filters:{
       prefix: function(inputPrefix, string){
               console.log(inputPrefix);
               return inputPrefix + string;
    }
```

and access it like:

```
 <p :v-text="'hello' | inputPrefix"></p>
```

or a computed property.

Comment: This still causes the not defined issue.

Comment: Is your prop declared in the component? 

props: [inoutPrefix] or props: { inputPrefix: { //validation }}

Comment: Yes the prop is declared

Comment: Ok. So you say: This still causes the not defined issue. 

But what is undefined at this point? this, or inputPrefix ?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'inputPrefix' of undefined`, so I guess it is `this`

Comment: And that is really weird. Where prefix(string) method is ? Is included your methods?

Comment: It's located under `filters:` not `methods`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the docs or refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828664/access-vue-instance-data-inside-filter-method) for explanation.

**Filters** should be pure functions which gives output based upon input. In your case you can use a computed property.

```js
Vue.component('mine', {
  props: ['prefix'],
  data() {
    return {
      value: ' component'
    }
  },
  template: '<p>{{formattedString}}</p>',
  computed: {
    formattedString() {
      return this.prefix + this.value
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: ['mine'],
  template: '<mine prefix="new" />'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you still wish to use a filter for your scenario, please find below

```js
Vue.component('mine', {
      props: ['prefix'],
      data() {
        return {
          value: ' component'
        }
      },
      template: '<p>{{value | format(prefix)}}</p>',
      filters: {
        format(value, prefix) {
          return prefix + value
        }
      }
    })

    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      components: ['mine'],
      template: '<mine prefix="new" />'
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```