# testCategories undefined in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I load my page I'm getting an undefined for my test categories. If I do this in my mounted section of vue `console.log(this.testCategories);` then I get an array of my categories, but if I do that to my filter section it gives me undefined.

I don't understand why that would be happening.

Here is my code

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <td>{{test.category | testCategory}}</td>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['testCategories'],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        computed: {

        },
        methods: {

        },
        filters: {
            testCategory(value) {
                console.log('testCategories', this.testCategories);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try `this.$props.testCategories` instead of `this.testCategories`.

Comment: Also, `test` is referenced in the template, but it's undefined in your components data.

Comment: probably its triggered even before its got value in it. try `if(this.testCategories){console.log(this.testCategories)}`

Comment: Filters are stateless, they do not have access to `this`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access vue instance/data inside filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828664/access-vue-instance-data-inside-filter-method)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your property to `test`, that has a member `category`.  Or refer to the declared property `testCategories`

```
 <theComponent :test='{category:"foobar"}' :testCategory='foobar' />
```

```
{
       props: ['test', 'testCategory'],
      
}
```